# What is the most efficient way to check if an URL is valid/exists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking for the fastest method to retrieve whether or not an URL exists.
I'd like to do the test on a list of URLs.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
import httplib
c = httplib.HTTPConnection('www.stackoverflow.com')
c.request("HEAD", '')
if c.getresponse().status == 301:
   print('Good news. Website is valid')
```

Comment: make sure to install httplib

Comment: your comment is unrelated.